# SSIS How To Extract Multiple .ZIP Files To Multiple Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2008, foreach, ssis, bids

**Problem/Scenario:**

Inside of a directory I have multiple .zip archives. Each of these contain mulitple .csv files. I need to extract the contents of each .zip archive to a directory of the same name as the source .zip archive:

```
C:\MyDirectory\Data1.zip extract files to C:\MyDirectory\Data1
C:\MyDirectory\Data2.zip extract files to C:\MyDirectory\Data2
```

I have a Foreach Loop which contains an Execute Process Task.  The task uses 7zip to extract the contents of each directory.  This task has the following variables set:

```
varZipSourceFolder = \\<server>\c$\MyDirectory
varZipDestination  = \\<server>\c$\MyDirectory\
varZipFileName
varExePath         = C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe
```

The problem is that as of now, the task runs and extracts the files from the first archive successfully.  However, when moving to extract from the next .zip archive it is trying to extract to the first directory created:

```
C:\MyDirectory\Data1.zip is extracting to C:\MyDirectory\Data1
C:\MyDirectory\Data2.zip is extracting to C:\MyDirectory\Data1
```

Below are some screen grabs from the SSIS project in VS2008:

**ForEach Loop:**

[image: ForEach Collection Settings]

[image: ForEach VariableMappings]

**Execute Process Task:**

[image: ExecuteProcessTask Process]

[image: ExecuteProcessTask Expressions]

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Also, please let me know if I need to edit the question in any way to help communicate my problem better.

Comment: It looks like varZipDestination is where things are being extracted to. I would think you'd need to do some slicing and dicing of varZipFileName to be extract the base file name. Then apply an expression to concat that value with varZipSourceFolder

Comment: Do you have an expression on the varZipDestination variable?

Comment: I think I see what you guys are getting at... I need to create additional variables to "break apart" the ZipFileName to get the path in pieces and then use the pieces to create the ZipDestination path correct?

I am very new to SSIS and could use a point in the right direction if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a TON of time and profanity I've got it.

I ended up using @Joost's custom [Unzip Task](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/10/custom-ssis-component-unzip-task.html) to handle unzipping but getting that and the ForEach loop configured to work for my specific problem was a difficult task in its own right.

I went ahead and recreated my variables using the comments from @Joost and @billinkc.  It took me a second but I was finally able to wrap my head around what they were referring to by "slice and dice" of the variable.

I'll do my best to convey what was done in case anyone else comes across this in their research.

**Answer/Solution:**

First, I recreated my variables from scratch.  I specifically made sure to include one that would be used for Joost's Unzip Task as the Destination Variable, and one as the Source Variable.  These variables are evaluated as expressions below along with the other variable definitions:

```
varUnzipTaskSource = @[User::varServer] + "\\" + @[User::varZipSource] + "\\" +  @[User::varZipFile] + ".zip"
varUnzipTaskDestination = @[User::varServer]  + "\\"  + @[User::varZipSource] +  "\\" + @[User::varZipFile] + "\\"

varServer    = \\MyServer\c$
varZipSource = \MyFolder
varZipFile   = MyFileName (no extension in the filename)
```

Next, I set my ForEach Loop container as follows:

*Note: Use UNC path and select Name Only*
[image: ForEach Collection Settings]

*Note: the Name Only selection will be used to create the Destination directories.*
[image: ForEach Variable Mappings]

And now the Unzip Task configuration:

[image: Unzip Task Configuration]

In summary, breaking apart the path to the Source and Destination was key.  The ForEach Loop grabs the Name Only of each .zip archive, creates a directory based off of that value, then extracts the data to it.

I will also be trying to get this to work without using Joost's custom task.  I will update this answer (if possible) with that info.

Thanks again to @Joost and @billinkc for getting me moving in the right direction.